# Grepping in specific ROS packages?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to quickly grep for keywords in a specific ROS package. I have installed and tried *recoll* as described in [rosgrep wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosgrep) but I am not satisfied as it does not follow standard grep syntax and does not provide context for the keywords.

I could not find an appropriate "Tools" component in trac to post a feature request, so I'll ask the question here what's the best way to grep when you're looking for context and a guaranteed synchronized search result?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9586/grepping-in-specific-ros-packages?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll give one possible answer myself. Creating my own 'rosgrep' script, this exactly matches my requirements.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 pkg=$(rospack find $1)
 shift
 grep --exclude-dir=\.svn --exclude-dir=bin --exclude-dir=build --exclude-dir=lib $* -r $pkg --color=always
```

Resulting in

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) with karma: 960 on 2011-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1